# Display random values from JSON data

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

I'm trying to get a new image appear each time the `a` tag is hovered. I've the getJSON request working, but I can't seem to randomise the result of the function.

I have this JSON data available:

```
[
 {"url":"http:\/\/image1.jpg"},
 {"url":"http:\/\/image2.jpg"},
 {"url":"http:\/\/image3.jpg"},
 {"url":"http:\/\/image4.jpg"}
]
```

My getJSON request looks like this:

```
  $('.imagehover').on(
    'mouseenter',
    function() {
      $.getJSON('images.json', function(result) {
        $.each(result, function(i, field){
          var urlPorperty = Object.keys(jsonData.url);
          var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlPorperty.length);
          var imageUrl = urlPorperty[index];
          $("#imagetestresult").html("<img src=" + field.url + ">");
        });
      });
    }
  );
```

HTML here:

```
<a href="#" class="imagehover">Images
<div id="imagetestresult"></div></a>
```

Any advice would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The callback argument is already an javascript object, you don't need to parse it.
2. jQuery.html() only print string of html directly to the selected element content. If you want to display the url as an visible image, you can show it using css background-image property

to do that, on you success callback

```
function (jsonData) {
    // obtain all the property as they are image url
    var urlPorperty = Object.keys(jsonData.data);
    // random pick an index
    var index = Math.floor(Math.random() * urlPorperty.length);
    // get the url base on the index
    var imageUrl = urlPorperty[index];
    // assign the image to #imagetestresult background image
    $('#imagetestresult').css('background-image', `url(${imageUrl})`);

}
```

---

Update 1

you can simplify the url json into same level array

```
{
    "url": [
        "http:\/\/image1.jpg",
        "http:\/\/image2.jpg",
        "http:\/\/image3.jpg",
        "http:\/\/image4.jpg"
    ]
}
```

as Shiva Pandey point out, trigger an ajax on mouse event may not be practical. Since the ajax is asynchronous, there are time taken for the http and the user experience may not be very smooth. Anyway.

```
$('.imagehover').on('mouseenter', function() {
    $.getJSON('images.json', function(result) {
        // random pick an index
        var index = Math.floor(result.url.length * Math.random());

        // replace the content with a <img>
        $("#imagetestresult").html($('<img>', {
            src : result.url[index]
        }));
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you! I've updated my post with your advice, but I still can't get it to work. Any suggestions on where I'm going wrong? All the best

Comment: The format of the json is changed and the callback is changed. It become a different question now and the answer is invalid. There are logic and runtime error in your code. e.g. 1. jsonData is undefined and so jsonData.url is. 2. the subject said to display the random value, so why would you traverse all the url in sequence?

Comment: Apologies, I'm very new to this and can't find the right information. Could this function still work with this format of json? If I define the jsonData and jsonData.url? I'm not quite sure what traverse all the url in sequence means. It would be great if you could explain. Many thanks again for your advice

Comment: Lets make thing clear before we update the answer. Do you have the full control on the json structure? Because it has some redundant level there and we can trim it a little bit.

Comment: I do yes, I'm using kirby cms to generate the json

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you :) I'm getting a problem now where the mouseover sometimes causes the image to load many times very quickly, while other times it only loads one image until the next mouseenter. Is this because I'm doing the ajax call on each mouseenter? Many thanks

Comment: I fixed it by adding the mouseenter function inside the getJSON function. Thank you very much for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

The answer **Mr. Brickowski** is the perfect one. I would just like to add something more. Don't do the ajax call every time mouse enter event happens. It will cause you a lot of trouble later on. Instead make that ajax call at first and then save that data in some variables like urlProperty and on MouseEnter do the rest of random selection.